# Размещение блоков flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

как разместить блоки как на картинке НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЯ HTMl ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

левый квадрат не хочет занимать 100% высоты, а занимает 100% ширины(так у меня получилось)   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
        .last_request_wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .last_request_wrapper>* {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .last_request_container {
            display: flex;
            /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
            background-color: blueviolet;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .last_request_title {
            text-align: left;
            background: deepskyblue;
            /* flex: 3 0px; */
            /* order: 2; */
            width: 56%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            place-self: flex-end;

        }

        .last_request_photo {
            /* width: 64px; */
            /* height: 64px; */
        }

        img {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
        }


        .last_request_description {
            background: lightgreen;
            width: 50%;
            display: flex;
            place-self: flex-end;
        }
```

```html
<div class="last_request_wrapper">

        <div class="last_request_container">

            <div class="last_request_title">

                last_request_title

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_photo">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg"
                        alt="">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus
                voluptate
                ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non debitis
                repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

        </div>

        <div class="last_request_container">

            <div class="last_request_title">

                last_request_title

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_photo">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg"
                        alt="">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus
                voluptate
                ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non
                debitis
                repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

        </div>

        <div class="last_request_container">

            <div class="last_request_title">

                last_request_title

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_photo">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg"
                        alt="">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta
                natus voluptate
                ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure,
                dolores non debitis
                repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

        </div>

        <div class="last_request_container">

            <div class="last_request_title">

                last_request_title

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_photo">
                <div>
                    <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg"
                        alt="">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                Soluta natus voluptate
                ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto
                iure, dolores non debitis
                repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

        </div>





    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал это с помощью `display: grid`.

```css
.last_request_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.last_request_wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.last_request_container {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 64px 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.last_request_title {
  grid-column: 2;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.last_request_photo {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  
  align-self: center;
}

img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.last_request_description {
  grid-column: 2;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="last_request_wrapper">

  <div class="last_request_container">

    <div class="last_request_title">

      last_request_title

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_photo">
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus voluptate ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non debitis repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

  </div>

  <div class="last_request_container">

    <div class="last_request_title">

      last_request_title

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_photo">
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus voluptate ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non debitis repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

  </div>

  <div class="last_request_container">

    <div class="last_request_title">

      last_request_title

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_photo">
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus voluptate ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non debitis repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

  </div>

  <div class="last_request_container">

    <div class="last_request_title">

      last_request_title

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_photo">
      <div>
        <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/hair-beard-situation_amdtbGuUmZqaraWkpJRobWllrWdpZWU.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="last_request_description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta natus voluptate ducimus cum cumque. Similique animi aperiam dignissimos, expedita architecto iure, dolores non debitis repellendus accusantium saepe mollitia. Id, quos.</div>

  </div>





</div>
```

Comment: Все супер ! Хотел на flex делать, но пойдет . 